# How to change (⌘ + O) or (⌘ + ↓) shortcut that is used to open a file/folder to (⌘ + ↵)?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, big-sur

I recently formatted my macbook pro (Big Sur). Before formatting, I had set the shortcut to open a file to `⌘ + ↵`. But, now I do not know how to change the shortcut `⌘ + O` or `⌘ + ↓` to `⌘ + ↵`.

Comment: Are you saying that you've tried to change it (in System Prefs > Keyboard) but it didn't work, or that you just don't know how to change a shortcut? Also: what will you use to rename a file? If you think that Command O is File > Open, then it is the same in the Finder as every other app.

Comment: I went to (System Prefs > Keyboard), but I could not find a way to set the shortcut for file open from there. I can use ↵ for file rename (default). I want (⌘ plus ↵) for file open.